# Ruby - Can't require gem properly

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I'm trying to require the gem 'cerebrum'. I tried requiring it using the irb, and that worked, and also running the program in JRuby worked too. However, Ruby throws a LoadError.

`` C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- cerebrum (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require' ``

What am I doing wrong? Has anyone had that issue too?

Comment: What's the error message verbatim?

Comment: And the calling code? Are you using Bundler? binstubs? A version manager like RVM or chruby?

Comment: First of all, some troll has removed the error message from here. It said, "LoadError - Can't require such file". I am not using bundler or alike, just the normal ruby with the devkit installed. I've re-added the entire error message again.

Answer (score 0):

You get the load error when gem is not installed. First check if this gem is installed in this ruby version using **gem list cerebrum**. It may be installed in your jruby that's why it didn't throw error.

Comment: Cerebrum does show up in that list. But I get the idea of what you mean. I will try digging into it...